# Why is the output from a Array.prototype.map() of the result of a Array.prototype.filter() not an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to use the Array.prototype.some() function on what I think should be an array as the result of an Array.prototype.map() from .filter() I get

> .some is not a function

Here is a short snippet demonstrating the error with sufficient setup:

```js
// Get all options from dropdown
var options = $("#mySelect option");

// Get array of strings matching regex from options
var numbers = options.map(function (index, option) {
  return option.value.match("[0-9]+")[0];
});

// Attempt to use some on the numbers array
numbers.some(function (number) {
  console.log(number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Drop down menu with 10 options in words -->
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">One 1</option>
  <option value="2">Two 2</option>
  <option value="3">Three 3</option>
  <option value="4">Four 4</option>
  <option value="5">Five 5</option>
  <option value="6">Six 6</option>
  <option value="7">Seven 7</option>
  <option value="8">Eight 8</option>
  <option value="9">Nine 9</option>
  <option value="10">Ten 10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @webCatDev, You are absolutely correct for Array.prototype.map(). The problem/solution however is that this is actually JQuery not an array and the JQuery map function operates differently.

If I had been looking at the documentation at the time rather than just assume how it works  I would have certainly noticed that I was actually trying to operate in a JQuery object rather than a JS Array due to the differences in callback signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (I) are mixing up JS array functions and JQuery functions. The .filter() in your post is actually a JQuery function that returns a JQuery object. From there, map is another JQuery function returning JQuery and thus .some() on your object does not exist as it does not exist as a JQuery function.

A suitable solution would be to use the JQuery .each() function instead like this:

```js
// Get all options from dropdown
var options = $("#mySelect option");

// Get array of strings matching regex from options
var numbers = options.map(function (index, option) {
  return option.value.match("[0-9]+")[0];
});

// Iterate through your object with JQuery's .each()
numbers.each(function (index, number) {
  console.log(number);
  
  // You can return false to break this loop early similarly to .every() (or inversely to .some) on JS arrays
  if (number == 5){
    return false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Drop down menu with 10 options in words -->
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">One 1</option>
  <option value="2">Two 2</option>
  <option value="3">Three 3</option>
  <option value="4">Four 4</option>
  <option value="5">Five 5</option>
  <option value="6">Six 6</option>
  <option value="7">Seven 7</option>
  <option value="8">Eight 8</option>
  <option value="9">Nine 9</option>
  <option value="10">Ten 10</option>
</select>
```